# RxJava - blockingGet() method stops thread when using mergeWith operator

Tags: rx-java, blocking, rx-java2

I have a use-case where I need a feedback loop which will emit an item from already emitted items based on some condition.

Sample Code :

```
    Flowable<Integer> range1 = Flowable.range(1, 10);
    UnicastProcessor<Integer> publishProcessor = UnicastProcessor.create();

    Single<List<Integer>> pollResponse =  range1
            .mergeWith(publishProcessor) //On Commenting this line code works without wanted behaviour
            .map(integer -> {
                if (integer % 2 == 0 && integer <= 10) {
                    publishProcessor.onNext(20 + integer);
                }
                return integer;
            })
            .flatMap(integer -> flatMapMock(integer, publishProcessor))
            .toList()
            .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println(throwable));

    List<Integer> integers = pollResponse.blockingGet();
    System.out.println(integers.size());
```

flatMapMock function :

```
private static Flowable<Integer> flatMapMock(Integer integer, 
    FlowableProcessor<Integer> feedbackSource){

    return Flowable.just(integer)
            .map(integer1 -> integer1);
}
```

My question is:

- If I don't merge the publishProcessor with range1 flowable, then I
  am reaching till printing list size. **However, on merging why doesn't
  it work ?**
- Am I missing anything here ? Any pointer would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `toList` which requires a finite stream, but you merge in the `UnicastProcessor` which is never completed thus the `mergeWith` never completes. You should likely rethink what you wanted to achieve.